# Only 4GB RAM out of 8 shown in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit and in BIOS

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, ram

I have seen similar questions and answers but mine is:

a. I have 8GB RAM installed

b. My BIOS shows 4GB

c. Ubuntu's System Setting/Details shows 3.7GB (but this small decrease is not a great issue for me)

Question:

Is this a possible Ubuntu issue or it has to do with my pc hardware (faulty memory, etc..)?
Sorry, I am a noobie, but what I mean is: if it should be an Ubuntu issue, would the BIOS show the right RAM amount (8GB)? Or Ubuntu "affects" also what is shown in the BIOS settings?

Thanks a lot in advance for your patience and for your help with this.

Alex

Answer (score 2):

If the BIOS shows only 4GB, it's a hardware problem. One of your chips is not working, or quite possibly, one of your chips is not properly seated. (Or you actually have 4GB.)

Under Linux, the command `sudo dmidecode -t 6` (from the [dmidecode](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dmidecode) [image: Install dmidecode] package) will tell you which memory banks have a chip connected and what size chip. If some banks are reported empty but you think there is a chip in them, take the cheap out and insert it back, making sure to seat it properly.

Comment: I have dual-bank motherboard and I made sure each of the 4GB module was seated into a same colour bank. However, it shows only as "single bank" connected. Could that be the problem? Here is an excerpt (only one bank) from dmidecode: Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
 Socket Designation: A0
 Bank Connections: 1
 Current Speed: Unknown
 Type: Other
 Installed Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
 Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Single-bank Connection)
 Error Status: OK

Comment: @AlexdM This output is from a 2GB module. Do you have 2x2GB? 4x2GB? Evidently you don't have 2x4GB!

Comment: @AlexdM I still think you have 2 modules of 2GB each. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks for replying. Well, I think otherwise because I had in my hands 2 x 4GB Modules like these (http://www.corsair.com/us/memory-by-product-family/xms-classic/cmx4gx3m2a1600c9.html), that is what I have installed.

Comment: @AlexdM You linked to a 4GB kit, consisting of two 2GB modules.

Comment: thanks but I'm sorry to insist, on the actual memory module is written "4GB" I'll take a picture if needed ;-)

Comment: @AlexdM I'm sorry to insist, but the reference you linked to is a 2x2GB kit, totalling 4GB. Are you sure the module doesn't read “4GB kit” or the like? Also, try `dmidecode -t 17`, it may display more information like the part number (not all chips report it).

Comment: I hear what you say and you must be right. Still don't get why Corsair would write 4GB on a 2GB memory module. Also, what is a "kit"? I mean if, according to you, I have 2 x 4GB kit (made of 2+2 each) why can't I use the 4GB in each "kit"? I run dmidecode but I dont know how to stick the result here because it says it is too long. I tried to indent 4 spaces to do the <pre> <code> formatting but i must do something wrong because it is not working...by the way, thanks for your patience and help ;-)

Comment: @AlexdM A kit is two modules that have exactly the same characteristics and are meant to be used together. Most RAM banks have two physical slots that plug into the same bank, and work best when identical modules are in the two slots. You have one 4GB kit which consists of two 2GB modules. Labeling the modules with the kit size is confusing but common practice.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Gilles, yet still I do not understand how I could utilise both "parts" of 2GB each of the 4GB kit. The modules are fully seated in the the MB slots but why I can only see one (the 2GB) "part" of each kit only?

Comment: @AlexdM You have two modules, right? Two modules (each 2GB) make one kit. The kit has two 2GB parts for a 4GB total.

Comment: yes you right each module of 4GB included 2x2GB (see phot of my 2 modules here http://s14.postimage.org/598v2qi6p/memory.jpg )but this still doesn't answer my qustion on how I could enable each kit to use 4GB instead of 2GB so to have a total of 8GB instead of 4GB> I also tried to swap module on different MB slots. Nothing changed. Still 4GB.

Comment: @AlexdM Module = stick = piece that you can hold in your hand separately. Kit = a set of two modules: a kit comes in two separate pieces that are meant to be used together. The photo shows two modules. The label “4GB (2x2GB)” means that each of the two sticks contains 2GB, and the total storage capacity shown in the photo is 4GB.

Comment: I feel rathe embarrassed hahaha now I understand...feeling a bit stupid but eventually, with your patience I managed to understand that! Sorry for the confusion, you are right. I now realise I have 4G on board. End if the story...haha...thanks again!